# How to stop or pause a scheduled job in Liferay 6.1

Tags: java, liferay, job-scheduling

I have a portlet that launches a *scheduled job*. But when I try to pause or stop it, the job continues executing. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong when creating the scheduled job or when I'm trying to stop/pause it.

Here is how I launch the job:

```
CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger("job1", "group1", "0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *");

SimpleJob job = new SimpleJob();
MessageBusUtil.registerMessageListener(DestinationNames.SCHEDULER_DISPATCH, job);

Message message = new Message();
message.put(SchedulerEngine.MESSAGE_LISTENER_CLASS_NAME, SimpleJob.class.getName());
SchedulerEngineUtil.schedule(trigger, StorageType.PERSISTED, 
    "Scheduled Job", DestinationNames.SCHEDULER_DISPATCH, message, 0);
```

Here is the job:

```
public class SimpleJob implements  MessageListener {
    private static Log log = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(SimpleJob.class);

    @Override
    public void receive(Message message) throws MessageListenerException {
        log.debug(" ... SimpleJob executed ... ");      
    }

}
```

And here is the function that tries to stop:

```
public void stopCron(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)throws Exception{
    SimpleJob job = new SimpleJob();

    MessageBusUtil.unregisterMessageListener(DestinationNames.SCHEDULER_DISPATCH, job);
    SchedulerEngineUtil.pause("job1", "group1", StorageType.PERSISTED);
    SchedulerEngineUtil.delete("job1", "group1", StorageType.PERSISTED);
    SchedulerEngineUtil.unschedule("job1", "group1", StorageType.PERSISTED);

}
```

How can I stop the job?

Comment: Since Liferay 6.2 it is `SchedulerEngineHelperUtil` - `SchedulerEngineUtil` is deprecated now, so I guess you are using a previous version of Liferay? You should always mention if you are using outdated versions, as it helps us to help you.

Comment: Yes I'm using Liferay 6.1

Comment: Even in 6.1.2 it is deprecated, so please be more specific.

Comment: Liferay plugins SDK 6.1.1  is the version

Answer (score 0):

First: you are unregistering the wrong instance of your job:

```
SimpleJob job = new SimpleJob();
MessageBusUtil.unregisterMessageListener(DestinationNames.SCHEDULER_DISPATCH, job);
```

The given job is not the instance that you have registered in

```
 MessageBusUtil.registerMessageListener(DestinationNames.SCHEDULER_DISPATCH, job);
```

As result the `unregisterMessageListener` will do nothing.

Second: you don't need to register any message listener at all. There is already one registered for you in `SchedulerEngineHelperUtil.schedule()`, using the `MESSAGE_LISTENER_CLASS_NAME` property from the message. But to use it correctly you will have to define the id of your portlet or web context as well:

```
String simpleJobClass = SimpleJob.class.getName();
message.put(SchedulerEngine.MESSAGE_LISTENER_CLASS_NAME, simpleJobClass);
message.put(SchedulerEngine.PORTLET_ID, "my-web-context or my-portlet-id");
message.put(SchedulerEngine.DESTINATION_NAME, DestinationNames.SCHEDULER_DISPATCH);
```

Now it should be possible to pause / cancel your job as given in your example:

```
SchedulerEngineUtil.delete("job1", "group1", StorageType.PERSISTED);
```

By the way: `MessageBusUtil.registerMessageListener(DestinationNames.SCHEDULER_DISPATCH, job)` will register your job for *all* scheduled triggers, as all of them use `SCHEDULER_DISPATCH` as destination name.

Answer (score 0):

first of all thanks for your answer! I tried it with your code, withour registering the message listener and the job doesn't fire.  But with the MessageBusUtil.registerMessageListener the job is fired but with the

```
SchedulerEngineUtil.pause("work1", "grupo1", StorageType.PERSISTED);
```

The job doesn't stop.

Code of launch:

```
String cron = "0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *";
    CronTrigger trigger = null;
    trigger = new CronTrigger("work1", "grupo1", cron); 

    SimpleJob job = new SimpleJob();

    Message message = new Message();
    message.put(SchedulerEngine.MESSAGE_LISTENER_CLASS_NAME, SimpleJob.class);
    message.put(SchedulerEngine.PORTLET_ID, td.getPortletDisplay().getId());
    message.put(SchedulerEngine.DESTINATION_NAME, DestinationNames.SCHEDULER_DISPATCH);



    MessageBusUtil.registerMessageListener(DestinationNames.SCHEDULER_DISPATCH, job);
    SchedulerEngineUtil.schedule(trigger, StorageType.PERSISTED, "Scheduled Job", DestinationNames.SCHEDULER_DISPATCH, message, 0);
```

And the stop in other function:

```
SchedulerEngineUtil.delete("work1", "grupo1", StorageType.PERSISTED);
```

Regards.

Comment: Adding an _answer_ in Stack Overflow means to answer your question. If you've got to comment on another answer, please use the button labeled _Add comment_ below that answer or edit your question to include the new information.

Comment: And can you try to use the class name as job name and group name? In some versions that was necessary, as far as I remember...

Comment: Class name in the delete method? I tried but continues working the job.